# Wrong bundle_option_qty into cart magento 2

Tags: magento, query-string, magento-2.0, request.querystring, querystringparameter

I'm trying to put into cart the selections of my bundle (query string) but I'm getting back always a wrong number of items into cart.

Below an example:
I have a bundle with bundle option 8664.
Inside this bundle option I have 2 selection A(12561) and B(12562).
I wanna put inside my cart 2 items for selection A e 3 items for selection B.
So when I go check out page I found 3 items for selection A and 3 items for selection B.

https://mywebsite/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jb2ZmZWUtc3lzdGVtLml0L2JveC1wZXJzb25hbGl6emF0bw,,/product/804/?&bundle_option[8684][]=12561&bundle_option_qty[8684]=2.0000&bundle_option[8684][]=12562&bundle_option_qty[8684]=3.0000

What is wrong with my code? There is some parameter that I have to set?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?